# Prove base times altitude is a constant without resorting to area.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

The area of a triangle is one-half base times altitude. This implies that, for $\bigtriangleup ABC$, $ah_A = bh_B=ch_C$, where $h_A$ is the length of the altitude dropped from point A to side BC, etc.

I want to verify that this can be proved without using the concept of area.

So far all I've managed to do is verify Heron's formula, which can be interpreted as a proof that $ah_A = bh_B=ch_C = 2\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$. So now I know that it can be done. My complaint is that I only wanted to show that  $ah_A = bh_B=ch_C$, not find the actual value. Does anyone have or know where I can find such a proof?

Comment: $h_A = c\sin B$, so that $ah_A = abc \frac{\sin B}{b} = \frac{abc}{2R}$ (which can be proved my trigonometry alone, no need to refer to area directly)

Comment: I think, since the value of R is unknown, that your proof does not directly assign a specific value to $ah_A$, which makes it the kind of proof I was looking for.

Comment: To be honest though, I was hoping for a synthetic proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use similar triangles concept. Let AA<sub>1</sub>, BB<sub>1</sub>, CC<sub>1</sub> - altitudes, then:

1) triangels AA<sub>1</sub>C is similar to BB<sub>1</sub>C (two angles), so AA<sub>1</sub>/BB<sub>1</sub> = AC/BC, or *ah<sub>a</sub>=bh<sub>b</sub>*

2) triangels BB<sub>1</sub>A is similar to CC<sub>1</sub>A (two angles), so BB<sub>1</sub>/CC<sub>1</sub> = AC/AB, or *bh<sub>b</sub>=ch<sub>c</sub>*

So *ah<sub>a</sub>=bh<sub>b</sub>=ch<sub>c</sub>*

Comment: This is circular.  The theorems about similar triangles are proved using areas.